# Why auc score decreased on bigram model?

Tags: svm, roc, auc, ensemble-learning

I created 3 unigram,bigram and trigram.After that i vectorize them with sklearn vectorizer.then i split data to training set and test set.then i train svm and bagged svm with this three model.auc score decreased on bigram model.what is the problem?lets show some code
here i read bigram fearure.bigram features line: **digital camera , indoor images**

```
df_unigram=pd.read_csv('unigram.csv')
df_bigram=pd.read_csv('bigram.csv')
lst_unigram=df_unigram.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
lst_bigram=df_bigram.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
```

then i combine features like that:
    lst_bigram=lst_bigram+lst_unigram

after that i covert above list to dictionary.because TfidfVectorizer get dictionary off features and make vectorize base on features and sentences

i have imbalance dataset that contains **135 neg sentences and 365** pos sentences.here i split dataset:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
sentence_train, sentence_test, polarity_train, polarity_test = train_test_split(lst_sentences, lst_polarity, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

and here i vectorize models

```
vectorizer2 = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=set(dic_bigram_features),ngram_range=(1,2))
tf_idf_train2=vectorizer2.fit_transform(sentence_train)
tf_idf_test2=vectorizer2.fit_transform(sentence_test)
```

and this is my fuction that give model type like bigram,trigram and ... and returns auc score

```
def svm_predictions(model_type):
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
if model_type=="uni":
    clf=SVC(C=100.0,kernel='linear',probability=True)
    clf.fit(tf_idf_train1, polarity_train)
    probs = clf.predict_proba(tf_idf_test1)
    preds= probs[:,1]
    fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(polarity_test, preds)
    roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
if model_type=="bi":
    clf=SVC(C=100.0,kernel='linear',probability=True)
    clf.fit(tf_idf_train2, polarity_train)
    probs = clf.predict_proba(tf_idf_test2)
    preds= probs[:,1]
    fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(polarity_test, preds)
    roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
if model_type=="tri":
    clf=SVC(C=100.0,kernel='linear',probability=True)
    clf.fit(tf_idf_train3, polarity_train)
    probs = clf.predict_proba(tf_idf_test3)
    preds= probs[:,1]
    fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(polarity_test, preds)
    roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
return roc_auc
```

and this is my results on unigram and bigram and trigram model for **svm and bagged svm**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Avlg.png)

...

Comment: I have two problems.i read in article svm performs not good in imbalanced datasets.but i see it has good result in ratio 1:3

Comment: second problem is in article results on svm is weaker than svm+oversample methods on imbalanced datasets.but i see here most of the time svm perform better than svm+oversample on this model of datasets

Comment: You need to clarify that in the question itself. Be clear and specific if you want to get good answers.